# Grid badly displayed using ggplot2

Tags: r, map-projections, ggplot2

I am trying to plot celestial object on the sky (basically with coordinates equivalent to latitude/longitude). I successfully plotted all my points using the `"aitoff"` projection of the `coord_map` function, but in this case, the grid is badly displayed, i.e. residual horizontal lines are still displayed for latitudes non equal to zero along with their correct projections.

[image]

How could I remove these lines?

Here is code that reproduces the behavior:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mapproj)
sky2 = data.frame(RA=0, Dec=0)
skyplot2 <- qplot(RA,Dec,data=sky2,xlim=c(0,360),ylim=c(-89.999,89.999),
xlab="R.A.(°)", ylab="Decl. (°)",main="Source repartition on the sky")
skyplot2 + coord_map(projection="aitoff",orientation=c(89.999,180,0)) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks=(-2:2)*30,limits=c(-89.999,89.999)) + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=(0:8)*45,limits=c(0,360),
                   labels=c("","","","","","","","",""))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>Definitely this is a bug in ggplot2 so could you please file this bug?
https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues?state=open</del> [Filed as a bug](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/562).

Here is a quick and dirty hack.

```
f <- function(x, y, ...) {
    if (any(is.na(x))) {
    id <- rle(!is.na(x))$length
    id <- rep(seq_along(id), id)
    df <- data.frame(x, y, id)
    df <- df[order(df$id, df$x), ]
  } else if (any(is.na(y))) {
    id <- rle(!is.na(y))$length
    id <- rep(seq_along(id), id)
    df <- data.frame(x, y, id)
  }
  polylineGrob(df$x, df$y, id = df$id, gp = gpar(col = "white"))
}

skyplot2 <- qplot(RA,Dec,data=sky2,xlim=c(0,360),ylim=c(-89.999,89.999),
                  xlab="R.A.(°)", ylab="Decl. (°)",main="Source repartition on the sky")
skyplot2 + coord_map(projection="aitoff",orientation=c(89.999,180,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=(-2:2)*30,limits=c(-89.999,89.999)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=(0:8)*45,limits=c(0,360),
                     labels=c("","","","","","","","","")) +
                    opts(panel.grid.major = f)
```

[image]

Note that this may work only with the aitoff projection.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add:

```
+ opts(axis.ticks = theme_blank())
```

Comment: Hmm. That gets rid of the ticks at the bottom of the figure, but not the extra (straight) horizontal lines that the OP wants to remove.